# How do I resolve an issue with Index/Match returning errors?

Tags: excel, vba, match, lookup

I am attempting to use an index/match combo to bring in a value from a defined table, "tblPlant1". The issue lies with an "Error 2015" from the Match function and an issue with the Index function. I ultimately want to incorporate the match result in the Index function. I understand the <255 limit of the error 2015 but struggle to understand how it arrives at the error based on the lookup value and lookup array. Code, Debug.Print output and table is below. Thanks in advance.

```
Dim plantcode As String
Dim tblPlant1 As ListObject
Dim matchresult As Variant
Dim errormsg As String
Dim VIN As String
Dim Plant1 As Variant

Set tblPlant1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("tblPlant1")

VIN = ActiveCell.Value
plantcode = Mid(VIN, 11, 1)
errormsg = "Error: Plant Code " & Chr(34) & plantcode & Chr(34) & " (VIN Digit 11) Not Found"


matchresult = Application.Match(plantcode, tblPlant1.ListColumns("VIN"), 0)

Plant1 = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Index(tblPlant1.ListColumns("Plant"), 6), errormsg)


Debug.Print errormsg
Debug.Print VIN
Debug.Print plantcode
Debug.Print matchresult
Debug.Print Plant1
```

Output of the Debug is below:

Error: Plant Code "H" (VIN Digit 11) Not Found

1HTKSSWK9KH067162

H

Error 2015

Error: Plant Code "H" (VIN Digit 11) Not Found

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP0pB.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `matchresult = Application.Match("*" & plantcode & "*", tblPlant1.ListColumns("VIN"), 0)` return?

Comment: It also returns "Error 2015".

Comment: Try recreating the match as a formula in the worksheet... `=Match(...)` and get it to work. That should hopefully help determine why the VBA attempt isn't working.

Comment: Try `matchresult = Application.Match(plantcode, tblPlant1.ListColumns("VIN").DataBodyRange, 0)`

Comment: That worked, Tim! Thanks. And thanks to both of you for being willing to help.